# Is there a way to automatically correct the coordinates when click of a button to play?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first JS game (http://youfile.vip/luckybrick). My problem is how to auto change button coordinates depends on client window sizes. Please help me!

Comment: Can you include the minimum amount of code to reproduce your problem? Also, what have you tried to do so far? See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This question falls under link only questions which need to be fixed. if you have specific problem, include as much as code possible, excluding unrelated code. explain what you want to achieve and what is the issue clearly and add screenshots if necessary.